# jQuery infinite Carousel: Slide # 2 replaced by Slide # 3 on first iteration

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel, infinite-carousel

I am building an infinite jQuery carousel. Infinite being that it shows the first slide right after the final slide is shown to the user. To achieve this, I make this little tweak in the post complete callback function

`$('#slide li:last').after('#slide li:first')`.

This basically what makes the infinite slideshow happen. However, it messes up the **second slide** in particular. At the very first iteration of going from slide 1 to slide 2, slide 2 gets replaced by slide 3 (and it happens really quickly) . Every subsequent iteration works fine with slide 2 rendering itself as slide 2 and not slide 3.

To further understand this example, please take a look at the following js fiddle that captures all the necessary HTML, CSS, jQuery.

[jsfiddle for jQuery infinite carousel/slideshow](http://jsfiddle.net/parijatkalia/386Ak/10/)

Anybody know what's up :) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its happening because upon the completion of the animation you're removing an `li` from the beginning of the `ul` and putting it at the end, thus reseting the `left_indent` by a multiple of 1 element.

A simple fix is to do `$('#slides ul').css({'left': 0});` instead of `$('#slides ul').css({'left': -item_width});`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bm8Tv/1/)

Answer (score 1):

much simpler way:

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ivibof/1/edit)**

```
function slideshow(){

 var item_width = $('#slides li').outerWidth(true);

 $('#slides ul').stop().animate({left:-item_width},1200, function(){
     $('#slides li:last').after( $('#slides li:first') );
     $('#slides ul').css({left:0});
 });

}
```

Comment: awesome, thanks, You and @smazurov both got the right answers, I upvoted both but awarded the answer to the one who replied first :) Appreciate it :)